# Insert data from a table to another one in MySQL with where condition

Tags: mysql

I tried this command to insert all records from tblDoXang into tblDoXang1 which satisfy where condition:

```
insert into gtse.tblDoXang1
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
 -- where accountID = 'anhtuaniphone' and deviceID = '14C-10152'
-- and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-11-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-17 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)));
```

It showed me the message: `7432 row(s) affected`. After that, I check the data in new table(tblDoXang1) with this query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(thoiGian), nhienLieu
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang1`
```

and then I saw: `7432 row(s) returned`. I also checked where condition with the old table(tblDoXang):

```
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
 -- where accountID = 'anhtuaniphone' and deviceID = '14C-10152'
-- and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-11-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-17 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)));
```

It returned 7432 rows too. However, when I test with a specific value, I received two different results(I expected they were the same). This query returned two records(I select from the new table):

```
select from_unixtime(thoiGian), nhienLieu
from gtse.tblDoXang1
where
(from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-10-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-18 23:59:59')
and accountID = 'vinhnghia' 
and deviceID = '14C-00263'
```

while this threw 5 records(with the same condition)(I select from the old table with the condition I used to insert in the first query above):

```
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
        where accountID = 'vingnghia' and deviceID = '14C-00263'
       and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-10-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-18 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)));
```

I confused of this result and I didn't know exactly where was I wrong, so can someone give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the accountID supposed to be the same in those last two queries? vinhnghia and vingnghia?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson yes, accountID, deviceID and time were the same

Comment: I notice the time is different in those two queries, too. Just to rule out the differences, can you rerun them using accountID='vingnghia', deviceID='14C-00263', and time between '2014-10-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-18 23:59:59' and post the results?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson I edit the time, but result still did not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was not good. Please imagine that you have ten accounts in total. With this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
 -- where accountID = 'anhtuaniphone' and deviceID = '14C-10152'
-- and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-11-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-17 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)));
```

you will only receive the max value(of `nhienLieu`) in each one hour of ten accounts not of one account(which you expected). So it is the reason why the result was difference between two cases: when you specified specifically accountID,deviceID and thoiGian and when you selected all in your table. I think that this query will satisfy you goal:

```
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
 -- where accountID = 'anhtuaniphone' and deviceID = '14C-10152'
-- and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-11-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-17 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        accountID,deviceID);
```

Pls try it and show me any problems if you get.

Comment: `group by accountID,deviceID` is all I lacked before. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have found my mistake. In this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
 -- where accountID = 'anhtuaniphone' and deviceID = '14C-10152'
-- and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-11-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-17 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)));
```

I didn't specify time, accountID and deviceID. It was different from:

```
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
        where accountID = 'vingnghia' and deviceID = '14C-00263'
       and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-10-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-18 23:59:59'
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)));
```

Where I had specific where condition. So the query:

```
select from_unixtime(thoiGian), nhienLieu
from gtse.tblDoXang1
where
(from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-10-01 00:00:02' and '2014-11-18 23:59:59')
and accountID = 'vinhnghia' 
and deviceID = '14C-00263'
```

correspond to this:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(thoiGian), nhienLieu
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM `gtse`.`tblDoXang`
where concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), nhienLieu) in
    (select
        concat(date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)), max(nhienLieu))
        from gtse.tblDoXang
        group by
        date(from_unixtime(thoiGian)),
        hour(from_unixtime(thoiGian)))
) as t
where accountID = 'vinhnghia' 
and deviceID = '14C-00263'
and from_unixtime(thoiGian) between '2014-10-01 00:00:00' and '2014-11-18 23:59:59'
order by thoiGian asc;
```

That is the reason why I got the different result from two query above.